# S_ISREG returns 0

Tags: c, file-io, posix

So I want to test if a file given is regular or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Input check.
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stdout,"Format: %s <filename.txt>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    // Make sure the file is a regular file.
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) == -1)) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    struct stat st;
    if ((fstat(fd, &st) == -1)) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (!(S_ISREG(st.st_mode))) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Error, invalid file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I run: `.\a in.txt`

I don't know what exactly is going on, but when I'm trying to test if the file is regular (last if statement), it fails. I tested to see if fstat fails, but it doesn't.

Comment: Note that your `fprintf`+`strerror` calls can be more easily expressed via `perror` (although it would print to `stderr` instead of `stdout`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) == -1)) {
```

The equality operator `==` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So the above parses as:

```
if (fd = (open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) == -1)) {
```

Which assigns to `fd` the result of the comparison which will be either 0 or 1.  These values both happen to be valid open file descriptors for stdin and stdout so the `fstat` call is successful and gets you the status of one of these streams.

You'll need to adjust the parenthesis to do the assignment first:

```
if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
```

Also, it looks like you have other `if` statements that have a redundant set of parenthesis that you can remove.  You want to avoid this because those extra parenthesis can silence warnings about exactly what you did.